# Invalidcastexception thrown assigning null to type nullable decimal

Tags: c#

I put it back here as I am not dreaming.

Symptom: I am unable to assign null value to type decimal?. Assigning null throws exception.

```
decimal? value = (decimal?) null;
```

This time I add a picture as evidence because apparently others do not believe my issue.

Problem persists. This is the full code I am not hiding anything. I recompiled, reloaded and restarted. I also expect this to be working. But it does not.

[image]

Has anyone experienced similar?

Comment: I believe this is correct. Try type casting it to default(decimal).

Comment: no need to add that type cast. you can either assign a null or a value.

Comment: This statement isn't the problem; most likely VS is lying to you about the location of the exception, based on outdated debugging symbols (or the JIT over-optimizing things beyond reconcilability). Try rebuilding stuff, or failing that hunt around in the surrounding lines for a more likely candidate of this trouble.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I suspected that as well. But running the code line by line causes the issue and the exception gets thrown. Next line is never reached.

Comment: @LeiYang tried both ways. I will try Jllalonde's proposal as well.

Comment: @Teddy, although your code works well but cast is redundant in your case its may be `decimal? value = null;`

Comment: Nevertheless -- on no version of the .NET Framework will this assignment cause that exception, save the possibility of a serious JIT bug. Eliminate the impossible, whatever's left, however improbable, must be the truth. Check the IL with a decompiler if necessary to see what's actually running. Even when you're stepping through code, VS can only tell you what's happening based on the source code and the debugging symbols; these typically match up with the actual code being executed, but there's no way for VS to verify that.

Comment: @Teddy, I'd just try to reproduce your problem but It does not give me any exception and code works well. so try to delete `obj` folder, clean and rebuild solution once

Comment: questions: what compiler version are you using? is it a recent one? also: is it perhaps razor (cshtml) or some other late-compiled thing? basically: there are two options I can think of here: 1) the IDE is lying about the location, or 2) the compiler is genuinely broken, which seems incredibly unlikely, but would seem likelier if you're using "older" rather than "newer" (and razor etc is different again - it is a separate compilation mechanism)

Comment: Can you post the exception details?

Comment: @all Jeroen was right at the end. VS truely lies about it. I do not know why as I rebuilt the solution. I commented out the line before and after and the problem gone. THANK YOU ALL!

Comment: Do you have valid *pdb* files (i.e. does VS stop on the correct line?). Try removing (with back up) `*.pdb` files, and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Any specific reason why typecasting null to (decimal?) during assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Clean your solution and make sure that you debug your application in the DEBUG mode or have some debugging symbols from the current build. The code that you are showing is not throwing the exception, but something else from what you didn't shown is throwing this exception. For a prototype application, in up to date Visual Studio the sample code that you are showing works fine:

[image]

As you can see, the `(decimal?)` cast of null is not required, so you can just remove it and recompile your application.